# Edit author of an article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have post which belongs_to users, and would like an option when editing to be able to change the user that post is associated with.

I've made a start, but I am very new to Rails and a bit stuck.

I started in my post_controller.rb.

```
def update
    @post.user = associated_user
    if @post.update(post_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully updated"
        redirect_to edit_post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

I've defined the method associated_user in my application_controller.rb (I want to do this for a more than just articles.)

```
def associated_user
    @associated_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

I understand that this code is wrong - I don't want it to get the logged in user, I want to get it from the field I've set in my form view.

```
<%= f.text_field :associated_user, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Edit Author" %>
```

Ideally this form field would be a drop down listing all users with a certain status (a boolean I have already set in the users table.)

I'm not sure how far away I am, but if any one is able to offer some guidance, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are the relationships defined in the models. If your post belongs to users, then use a dropdown control in your form:

```
f.collection_select :user_id, User.whateverscope, :id, :text_method
```

and when the form is submitted rails will do the rest.

If you have something different set up, then post your models, your strong_params methods, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great start. I'm now showing just admins in the dropdown

`<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.where(admin: 'true'), :id, :username %>`

And yep, posts belongs_to users. How do I get that to update the user?

Comment: So long as user_id is included in `post_params`, `@post.update(post_params)` will update the user.

Comment: That did it! Amazing! Thanks so much.